# How can I check my code for copyright infringement

Tags: ios

I'm not sure exactly where to post this question but this website has been very helpful to me in the past.

I've made an iOS app for a client in Objective C and they are very worried about copyright infringement within the code. They are wanting to check the code for copyrighted materials but having a Google around I can't seem to find anything that helps me. All the code was written from scratch by me and the only third party stuff is Google Analytic code, everything else is all me but he is still worried about the code.

I know this is a website for programming problems but I could do with some advice.

Can sections of code be copyrighted that are essential to the software itself? e.g. could you copyright a for loop?

If I'm not allowed to post this here can anybody suggest somewhere that I can?

Comment: Just to clarify - does the client want to verify that you did not use copyrighted code in the development of the app, or is the client looking to copyright your code?

Comment: They want to verify that I did not use copyrighted code in the development of the app

Comment: Well, if they don't trust your word, they probably shouldn't have hired you... (Surely the way to handle this would be for you to sign a piece of paper that says you're responsible if they're sued for copyright violation in your code, and for you to have decent legal/liability insurance in case some moron sues when that's not actually the case. But that might be a better question for http://law.stackexchange.com...) #disclaimer

Comment: It's more of a fact that they are new to business and are worried about copyright infringement stopping their business.

Answer (score 1):

I am no lawyer, but my understanding is that in the U.S. you can copyright entire applications, software components, etc... but you cannot copyright a snippet of code (e.g. a for-loop).

So, if you copy and pasted some code off the internet, you should be okay. However, if you imported and used a 3rd party library that is copyrighted then you'd have to disclose that to your client, and they in turn would have to acknowledge somewhere within the application that portions of the application are under copyright by another entity. 3rd party libraries are meant to be used in other applications, so I doubt that there'd be any trouble unless your client did not acknowledge the provenance of said code in their application.

Generally speaking, companies get in copyright trouble when they contract an individual or business entity to develop their application without sorting out copyright claims, source code ownership, etc up front.

In the U.S., if you are a contractor developing an application for another company and that company does not meet the implicit requirements for source code ownership within the contracting arrangement, then they must explicitly define source code ownership or else face the possibility that the contracted developer will file a copyright claim on the application and force the company to pay to license the software.

In case you are wondering, a company implicitly owns the source code of an application if some or all of the following conditions are met:

1. The software is developed on company-owned hardware.
2. The source code is stored on company-owned hardware.
3. The tools needed to develop the software are provided by the company.
4. The software is part of the company's regular line of business.
5. The company already holds a copyright claim for the software (for situations in which the developer is adding features to or enhancing an existing software product)
6. Other provisions as determined by a court of law (may include things such as the nature and duration of the relationship between company and contractor, whether the contractor supplied his own copyrighted code as part of the application, etc)

All of the above is effectively moot, however, if the contractor signs a piece of paper that says that the company owns the software and all source code, and thus owns any and all past, present, or future claims to license, distribute, or create derivative works from the software. Most "serious" companies do this regardless of any of the implicit conditions above as a way to cover all their bases.

Comment: That's going to need a citation I think. "You can't copyright a for-loop" sounds made up.

Comment: @Doradus I didn't say "You can't copyright a  for-loop". You made up that I said that. I said my understanding is that you cannot copyright a code snippet. I am still no lawyer and would not hold myself to the truth of that, but it's my layperson's understanding. The rest of my ordered points are factual however.

Comment: That's a strange reaction, given that you literally said "you cannot copyright a snippet of code (e.g. a for-loop)."

Comment: @Doradus Quote out of context, though maybe the two phrases are too far from each other. I said "my understanding is ... you cannot copyright a snippet of code (e.g. a for-loop)"

Comment: Fair enough. But if that's the direction you're going -- if you proceed your entire answer with "I am no lawyer, but my understanding is..." and use that to wriggle out of responsibility to get the facts right -- then your answer has no value.

Comment: @Doradus I should probably just edit the answer because everything after "However, if you imported and used a 3rd party library..." I know to be true.